# Why is strtotime($lastmoment) bigger than time()?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, strtotime

The following code

```
 echo $lastmoment."<br/>";
echo time();
echo "<br/>";
echo strtotime($lastmoment);
```

outputs:

> 2009-12-15 17:40:53 1260876829
>   1260898853

What's wrong? $lastment is a past time stamp in MySQL, why is  strtotime($lastmoment) bigger than time()?

Comment: Can you add the following to your code, above the `echo time()`:  `echo $lastmoment;`? Seeing the value before it is converted with the `strtotime()` function would be helpful.

Comment: Also, maybe do several echos of the `$lastmoment` in a row, either before or after, to demonstrate that it remains constant. Thanks.

Comment: $lastmoment remains constant.

Comment: See Andrew's answer. Your servers have two different clocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL server is a different machine, or if the timestamp in $lastmoment was set from a different machine, you could be seeing clock drift. Check the system clocks on the various machines, and see if they agree.

Answer (score 0):

Because the time() function was may be executed some milliseconds before the $lastmoment.

EDIT:
Adding the comment to my thoughts, it might me that, the convert of strtotime() might have failed.
Or the date value from the database contains a value e.g. days which the date() does not have.
Be sure, that you compare 2 datevalues of the same format.

Comment: $lastmoment was fetched from database, which was a past time stamp.

Comment: $lastmoment's value is fixed.

Comment: If strtotime failed, it should throw a -1, and thus Dec 31st 1969. And even if the date value from the DB was more precise, etc, the whole point of strtotime is to convert any date/time to epoch. So even if it was to the millisecond, it would round off to epoch.